# Normalize a Unicode string to get its canonical representation

Tags: .net, unicode, normalization, diacritics, unicode-normalization

Given that for example `"à"` (one Unicode character) can also be encoded as `"\u0300a"` (two Unicode characters, i.e. a combining grave accent (U+0300) followed by an a), is there functionality in .NET to normalize a string so that the latter is converted into the former?

I believe the former is deemed the canonical representation. My particular issue is that I've seen cases where the latter isn't displayed correctly by some browsers, but this could be useful in other scenarios too.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it, duh! [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Fine. But just in case it might matter, the decomposed form of “à” is not U+0300 followed by the letter “a” but these characters in the opposite order. In Unicode, combining diacritic marks follow the character they relate to. This is different from the way we often type characters on European keyboards (pressing first a dead key for a diacritic, then a letter key—this normally produces a precomposed character, i.e. there is no combining diacritic involved). And you are right in the observation that precomposed characters often work better on output.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I was pretty sure it was the other way around! You're right, keyboard input using "dead keys" probably caused me to confuse the order.

Comment: Also, neither is universally considered canonical; both are equally correct Unicode strings. Some particular use-cases may consider a particular form canonical though. Since you mention browsers, this suggests that you're concerned with the web, and the W3C character model does insist on NFC, so you're not wrong, just overly-specific :)